# How do we slice individual items in a javascript list

Tags: javascript

Input :
`dates =  [201701, 201702, 201703]`

I want the output as `[2017-01, 2017-02, 2017-03]`

I tried using the slice method in javascript, but it fails

```
for (var i in dates) {
dates[i].slice(0, 4) + "-" + dates[i].slice(4);
}
```

It fails.

Comment: Side note: [Don't use `for in` to iterate over arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/227299)

Comment: "I tried using the slice method in javascript, but it fails" Numbers ain't Strings. You should be aware of the types you're dealing with.

Comment: For your next questions: don't just say it fails. Specify how it fails, does it give you wrong results? Does it throw an exception? What's the error message? Had you done that, you may have answered your own question because the console should say: `Uncaught TypeError: dates[i].slice is not a function` https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You just forgot `toString()`:

```js
var dates =  [201701, 201702, 201703];

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  console.log(dates[i].toString().slice(0, 4) + "-" + dates[i].toString().slice(4));
}
```

Comment: When I try the map method , it fails..                    
 dates.map(function(value, i){value.toString().slice(0, 4) + "-" + value.toString().slice(4);})

Comment: `for ... in` for an array is not recommended.

Comment: @NinaScholz Just pointed out the obvious error, changed now to `for`-loop though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) and [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for the wanted dates.

```js
var dates =  [201701, 201702, 201703],
    result = dates.map(a => a.toString().replace(/(?=..$)/, '-'));
    
console.log(result);
```

Or use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```js
var dates =  [201701, 201702, 201703],
    result = dates.map(a => a.toString().split(/(?=..$)/).join('-'));
    
console.log(result);
```

Both examples with ES5

```js
var dates =  [201701, 201702, 201703];

console.log(dates.map(function (a) { return a.toString().replace(/(?=..$)/, '-'); }));
console.log(dates.map(function (a) { return a.toString().split(/(?=..$)/).join('-'); }));
```

Comment: It's cool, but back references in RegExp make the code hard to read... At least for me. I think I see what it's doing (the two dots are the last two elements?) but slice is so much clearer.

Comment: it just looks if there are two characters left of the right, then replace ther, ort split.

Comment: This solution work fine in chrome, however fails in IE. IE does not recognize result = dates.map(a => a.toString().split(/(?=..$)/).join('-'));

Comment: It does not recognize => symbol. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @swat, you could use the classic function expression instead of an arrow function, please see edit.